# exponential time complexity

Tags: computational-complexity

given that:

$f(n) = a^n$ and 
$g(n) = b^n$

where, a,b are positive integers and n is a positive real number

does there exist some $f(n) \notin \mathcal{O}g(n)$?

ie. $f(n) \leq c_1 \cdot g(n)$ is false?

Comment: Sure, let $a=4$ and $b=2$. Or else we can grossly cheat and let $a=4$ and $b=1$.

Comment: see comment further down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $a > b$, $f(n) \not \in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$.

Comment: but if, say, a = 4 and b = 2, then couldnt you say that f(n) <= 0.5 g(n) and so the inequality still holds?

Comment: Consider $n = 10$. So $4^{10} = 2^{20} \geq 2^{10}$. If you wanted to switch the inequalities, $2^{10} \leq \frac{1}{2} 2^{20} = 2^{19}$.

Comment: ah, okay, sorry, i was getting my arithmetic all wrong. it would be the case that f(n) is in Og(n) if f(n) and g(n) were polynomial, but it is different for exponential. thanks for clearing that up, it helped me a fair bit in understanding it.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=4$ and $b=2$. We show that $a^n \not\in O(b^n)$. So we need to show that for every constant $c$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $4^n \gt c(2^n)$. Equivalently, since $4^n=(2^n)(2^n)$, we want to show that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $2^n \gt c$. This is clear, since $2^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: so then why is it not the case that a*n is not in O(b*n)?
surely this reasoning would hold if it was polynomial? a*n still tends to infinity as n tends to infinity.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that $a^n$ tends to $\infty$ much faster than $b^n$ does.

Comment: For $f(n)$ to be in $O(g(n))$, the ratio $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ must be $\le c$ for some **constant** $c$, whenever $n$ is large. The solution above shows that there is no such $c$.